# has_and_belongs_to_many validation such that users can't apply multiple times to a workshop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, relationship

Currently I'm building a system where users can apply to workshops... the only problem is that a user can apply multiple times.

This is the code for applying

```
      #apply to workshop
        def apply
          @workshop = Workshop.find(params[:id])
          @workshop.users << @current_user
          if @workshop.save
            @workshop.activities.create!({:user_id => @current_user.id, :text => "applied to workshop"})
            flash[:success] = "You successfully applied for the workshop"
            redirect_to workshop_path(@workshop)
          else
            flash[:error] = "You can't apply multiple times for the same workshop"
            redirect_to workshop_path(@workshop)
          end
        end
```

The Workshop model does the following validation:

```
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users #relationship with users...
      validate  :unique_apply
      protected

        def unique_apply
          if self.users.index(self.users.last) != self.users.length - 1
            errors.add(:users, "User can't apply multiple times to a workshop") 
          end
        end
```

And the save fails because the message "You can't apply multiple times for the same workshop" shows up.
But the user is still added to the workshop as an attendee? 
I think the problem is that the user is already added to the array before the save applies, then the save fails but the user isn't removed from the array.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Marcel

**UPDATE**
Added this in the migration so there are no duplicates in the database only ruby on rails doesn't catch the sql error, so it crashes ugly.

```
    add_index(:users_workshops, [:user_id, :workshop_id], :unique => true)
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

Fixed the problem by doing the following:

Create a join model instead of a has_and_belongs_to_many relation

This is the join model:

```
    class UserWorkshop < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :workshop

      validates_uniqueness_of  :user_id, :scope => :workshop_id

    end
```

This is the relationship definition in the other models:

In User:

```
      has_many                :workshops,         :through => :user_workshops
      has_many                :user_workshops
```

In Workshop:

```
      has_many                :users,     :through => :user_workshops, :uniq => true
      has_many                :user_workshops
```

Because you can only do a uniqueness validation on the current model you can't validate uniqueness on a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. Now we have a join model where we join users and workshops through, so the relationship in user and workshop stays the same the only BIG difference is that you can do validation in the join model. This is exactly what we want, we want to verify that there is only one :user_id per :workshop_id and therefore we use validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :workshop_id

Case solved!

P.S. Watch carefully that you mention the through relation (:user_workshops) as a separate has_many relation otherwise the model can't find the association!!

Comment: I added with PP some debugging info, the first is the amount of users before I add one user. The second is with one user added and the third is if the save failed. This is the response "Current users"
3
"Added one user"
4
"failed save"
4. So the added users stays in the array?

Answer (score 0):

According to "The Rails 3 Way", the "has_and belongs_to_man" is practically obsolete.

You should use has_many :through with an intermediate table.

Comment: I think I will do that because this seems to be almost impossible